# How to stop numbers being repeated in this VBA script

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have found this VBA script (running in powerpoint) and I just wanted to know how to stop numbers from being repeated. I did some google searches and I think the solution would be to create an array, and have the selected number go into the array. The script would then generate a new number as long as it skips all numbers in the array.

I'm just not sure how to implement this as I do not know VBA.

here is the script:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Dim chosenNum As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Sub randomNumber()
    lowRand = 1
    maxRand = 10
    Randomize
    For k = 1 To 10
        chosenNum = Int((maxRand - lowRand) * Rnd) + lowRand
        With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = chosenNum
        End With
        For I = 1 To 1
            Sleep (50)
            DoEvents
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Is it really 1 to 10? Nothing more? If it is then it might be better to run from 0 to 9 but this will not work with double digits. You can always add 1 to the final result for display.

Comment: `For I = 1 To 1` <-- what is the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

This will collect 10 unique single digit numbers (0 to 9) into a string and then split them into an array. As each is returned to the slide, 1 is added so the resut is 1 to 10.

```
Sub randomNumber()
    Dim lowRand As Long, maxRand As Long, strNum As String, chosenNum As String
    Dim k As Long, vNUMs As Variant

    lowRand = 0: maxRand = 10: strNum = vbNullString
    Randomize

    For k = 1 To 10
        chosenNum = Format(Int((maxRand - lowRand) * Rnd) + lowRand, "0")
        Do While CBool(InStr(strNum, chosenNum))
            chosenNum = Format(Int((maxRand - lowRand) * Rnd) + lowRand, "0")
        Loop
        strNum = strNum & chosenNum
    Next k

    vNUMs = Split(StrConv(strNum, vbUnicode), Chr(0))

    For k = LBound(vNUMs) To UBound(vNUMs)
        With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = vNUMs(k) + 1
        End With
        For I = 1 To 1
            Sleep (50)
            DoEvents
        Next
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thanks for that.To answer your question, the numbers could range from 1 to 80 up to 110.

Comment: In that case, use a scripting dictionary which comes with its own primary index **key**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you please explain?

Comment: I tested the script you wrote but it still repeats numbers.

Comment: Not when used for the purpose it was designed for; e.g. the parameters you specified in your question (1 to 10).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this to help you. The function is designed to return random integer numbers in the range you specify until all numbers in the range have been returned when it will then return -1. There is a test sub included to show how to use the function to get all numbers from 5 to 10.

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Copyright (c) 2015 YOUpresent Ltd.
' Source code is provide under Creative Commons Attribution License
' This means you must give credit for our original creation in the following form:
' "Includes code created by YOUpresent Ltd. (YOUpresent.co.uk)"
' Commons Deed @ http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
' License Legal @ http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit
Option Base 0 ' Explicitly set the lower bound of arrays to 0
Private iUsed As Integer ' count of all used numebrs

Public arrTracking() As String

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Returns a random number in a specified range without repeats
' Inputs:   iLow - integer representing the low end of the range
'           iHigh - integer representing the high end of the range
'           bReset - boolean flag to optionally reset the array
' Outputs:  returns an integer number or -1 if all numbers have been used
' Example first call: myNum = GetRandomNumber(10, 5, true)
' Example subsequent call: myNum = GetRandomNumber(10, 5)
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetRandomNumber(iLow As Integer, iHigh As Integer, Optional bReset As Boolean) As Integer
  Dim iNum As Integer     ' random number to be generated
  Dim InArray As Boolean  ' flag to test if number already used

  Randomize

  ' Reset the tracking array as required
  If bReset Then ReDim arrTracking(iHigh - iLow)

  ' If we've used all of the numbers, return -1 and quit
  If iUsed = iHigh - iLow + 1 Then
    GetRandomNumber = -1
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' Repeat the random function until we find an unused number and then
  ' update the tracking array, uncrease the counter and return the number
  Do While Not InArray
    iNum = Fix(((iHigh - iLow + 1) * Rnd + iLow))
    If arrTracking(iNum - iLow) = "" Then
      arrTracking(iNum - iLow) = "used"
      iUsed = iUsed + 1
      InArray = True
      GetRandomNumber = iNum
    Else
      'Debug.Print iNum & " used"
    End If
  Loop
End Function

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Test sub to get all random numbers in the range 5 to 10
' Inputs:   None
' Outputs:  Debug output of 6 numbers in the range 5 to 10 in then immediate window
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub GetAllRand()
  Dim iRndNum As Integer
  ' Get the initial number, restting the tracking array in the process
  iRndNum = GetRandomNumber(5, 10, True)
  Debug.Print iRndNum
  Do While Not iRndNum = -1
    iRndNum = GetRandomNumber(5, 10)
    Debug.Print iRndNum
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDF that you can use to populate an array with unique random numbers:

```
Function GetRandomDigits(amount As Integer, maxNumber As Integer) As Variant
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Do
            j = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, maxNumber)
            If Not .Contains(j) Then .Add j
        Loop Until .Count = amount

        GetRandomDigits = .ToArray()
    End With
End Function
```

And here's an example of how to use it:

```
Sub MM()

Dim nums As Variant

nums = GetRandomDigits(10, 100)

For Each num In nums
    Debug.Print num
Next

End Sub
```